# Tensorboard resume training plot

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I ran a reinforcement learning training script which used Pytorch and logged data to tensorboardX and saved checkpoints. Now I want to continue training. How do I tell tensorboardX to continue from where I left off? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out how to continue the training plot. While creating the summarywriter, we need to provide the same `log_dir` that we used while training the first time.

```
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter('log_dir')
```

Then inside the training loop step needs to start from where it left (not from 0):

```
writer.add_scalar('average reward',rewards.mean(),step)
```